# Snyk issue status in API - ignore, open, resolve

Tags: snyk

Is there any way in Snyk to run an API query for getting the status of a specific issue (ignored, open, resolved, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to get **aggregated issues**, but **not single ones** by id and per project, as far as I can see from Apiary
endpoint:
https://snyk.docs.apiary.io/#reference/projects/aggregated-project-issues/list-all-aggregated-issues

The response contains an 'ignored' boolean flag in each issue;
if it's "**resolved**" though, it should't be returned by the endpoint though at all anymore, as it's not an issue anymore